# Angular 2 + ng-xi18n + AOT no funciona

Tags: nodejs, angularjs-2.0, typescript, i18n

Estoy desarrollando la funcionalidad de cambio de idioma mediante botones definidos con etiquetas `<a/>`, de forma que el usuario pueda cambiar de idioma pulsando sobre el botón correspondiente al idioma en el que desea ver la web.

Para desarrollarlo, tomé como referencia el [proyecto QuickStart de Angular 2](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/setup.html), añadí la compilación [AOT y JIT](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html), luego añadí la utilidad de internacionalización ng-xi18n([versión JIT](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html) y finalmente, añadí el [módulo Gulp](http://rolandoldengarm.com/index.php/2016/10/17/angular-2-automated-i18n-workflow-using-gulp) para generar de forma automática los ficheros de otros idiomas.

Cuando compilo mi proyecto con JIT y lo ejecuto, mi funcionalidad de cambio de idioma funciona perfectamente.

El problema lo tengo cuando compilo mi proyecto con AOT y lo ejecuto. Mi utilidad de cambio de idioma ya no funciona.

**¿Donde puede estar el problema?**

Aquí os dejo el enlace a mi proyecto: https://github.com/Paulillo16/i18n-quickstart.git

Para compilarlo y ejecutarlo con JIT uso el comando `npm run start`.

Para compilarlo y ejecutarlo con AOT uso el comando `npm run start:aot`.

Para poder realizar la doble compilación mi proyecto cuenta con dos ficheros index.html y main.js.

Comment: Traducida...Gracias

Comment: ¿Ya solucionaste el problema?

Comment: Hola Juan Hernandez, de momento sigo sin encontrar la solución

Answer (score 0):

En la documentación https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/i18n.html
en la sección Internationalize with the AOT compiler dice básicamente que debes hacer un pre-build de la aplicación por cada idioma disponible, aunque no especifica como servir el html dependiendo de las preferencias de idioma del usuario.